How to disable the default of always auto connect to any new wifi network?
How to change the default configuration of always auto connect to any new wifi network it detects? I need to edit some generic default config manually? I need to recompile a patched wifi network app?
It just detected a new network.
I never connected to it.
It had no password (empty), and was shown as connected and with a padlock, how can that be?
This needs to be disabled by default: "connect automatically with priority", but it is enabled by default to anything new... to me that is really unsafe.
Anyway, I want to stop that unsafe behavior of auto connecting to any new network it detects.
I must decide if I trust the network or not before allowing it to auto connect.
Now, I have to be sure trusted wifi networks are available before enabling the wifi on my notebook, or it will crazly try to connect anywhere it think is ok.
So: Disabling must happen BEFORE the new network is detected, not after it connects unsafely, when I can do it manually, but could be too late.

Unable to reproduce: A stock 22.04 reinstall on a laptop recently behaved as expected. It did not connect to new networks until told to do so.

nmcli connection modify NewWifi1 connection.autoconnect-priority 10

@petep but that NewWifi1 is only possible after that network name is detected right? here, happened once at least, when I saw it was connected to that neighbor network that I never connected manually, and have no idea what the password is (and I dont even care knowing that..)

@user535733 could that mean my wifi got hacked?
